# add multiple Alarms and alarm sound in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, alarms

I am new to windows phone developing I am creating a simple alarm application like same as default alarm system which is installed on our windows phone. User can set multiple alarms
user can create alarm on another page and all alarms should be shown on Main_page and user can turn on or off alarms from Main_page through Toggle-switch how can I make it?? and I also want to play recorded sound which are recorded by user and stored on isolated storage when alarms fire. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the instructions here: [How to create alarms and reminders for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202965(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but there is one exception occurred on savebutton click event from addnotification.xaml page when I click on save button debugger show the message named 
" An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"
and debugger shows line with yellow colour on ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm); please help me

Comment: Most likely an alarm with the same `Name` property is already added to `ScheduledActionService`. Specify a different name each time you set the alarm. However, if you must use the same name, you can get the alarms already added by your application with `ScheduledActionService.GetActions<ScheduledNotification>()`, and check if any alarm with same name exists. Thereafter, you may remove that alarm and set your new alarm, or alert the user that an alarm already exists. It depends on what you app's logic is.

Comment: Thanks, any idea about set recorded file form user to set as alarm tone?

Comment: Sadly, sound files from IsolatedStorage are not supported for alarms. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm.sound(v=vs.105).aspx